# Is it faster to write <script defer> just before the </ head> tag than before the </ body> tag until the processing is completed?

Tags: javascript

Which of the following codes is faster to complete all processing?
I thought that code H was faster, but when I tried it, code B was faster (I think ...).
Depends on the environment?

code H

```
  <script src='js' defer></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

code B

```
  <script src='js' defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldn't know how to test it..  any test would be actually testing browser cache read internals or network speed which varies dep on many factors, you wont see any difference

Comment: To test, add 100mb of content between body in both scripts and test which one renders first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you define "faster". Faster to download? Execute?

By definition, scripts with `defer` always execute [when the DOM is ready](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#defer), but before the DOMContentLoaded event, regardless of where you put them. They would still need to be downloaded and only executed when they're supposed to - so the difference is almost unnoticeable.

Comment: I understood that difference is almost unnoticeable.